# Getting error SyntaxError: missing } after property list url: http://localhost/mcportal/public/post/comment/196675710685996,

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to resolve this error, i m using ajax request on php view file.

my code is here.

```
$( "body" ).on ("keypress", "#comment", function( event ) {
      if(event.which == 13)
                $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                        url: <?php echo 'localhot/mcportal/public/post/comment/196675710685996' ?>,
                        data: {},
                        success: function (response) {
                          alert( 'Comment posted' );
                      }
              });
            }
   });
```

Comment: $( "body" ).on ("keypress", "#comment", function( event ) {
      if(event.which == 13) {
        
            $.ajax({
            type: "post",
                    url: <?php echo 'localhot/mcportal/public/post/comment/196675710685996' ?>,
                    data: {},
                    success: function (response) {
                      alert( 'Comment posted' );
                  }
          });
        }
   });

Comment: i have opening brace in my code. in previous code i missed that. but actually i have it in my code. its trowing error in url line.

Comment: You should edit the question to add more information instead of adding them in the comments.

Comment: First: Why do you add code in a comment and not in your question? Second: Why are you echoing the string using PHP? Why not just write: url: 'localhost/......'? Oh.. and dont forget `http://` before the URL... or remove `localhost` and just write: `url: '/mcportal/....`

Answer (score 3):

You haven't added opening braces for your if condition

Answer (score 1):

You have to add opening `{` to your if-statement and quotes around your `url`. Otherwise your url will not be a string in your Javascript.

```
$( "body" ).on ("keypress", "#comment", function( event ) {
    if(event.which == 13)
    {       
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '<?php echo 'http://localhost/mcportal/public/post/comment/196675710685996' ?>',
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                alert( 'Comment posted' );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! If the problem is solved you should mark the answer as "accepted", so that others don't have to check this question again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for resolving this issue:

1. Add opening braces `{` for your if condition OR
2. Remove ending braces `}` (last one)